# How does multilevel inheritance implemented in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, multi-level

How is multilevel inheritance implemented in PHP using PHP magic methods?

I was asked in an interview "how will you implement multilevel inheritance using magic methods".

So I am eager to know about this.

Thx.

Comment: 2 vote downs ??? Any reason guys?

Answer (score 6):

It's not clear whether you mean "how does one use multilevel inheritance?" or "how is it implemented inside the PHP interpreter?".  If it's the former, then as follows:

```
class Animal
{
    ...
}

class Cat extends Animal
{
    ...
}

class Tiger extends Cat
{
    ...
}
```

If it's the latter, then I'm not sure it's possible to give a reasonable explanation in a few paragraphs here!

Comment: Thx for the reply ude. But I heard elsewhere that usage of magic functions is involved while implementing multilevel inheritance. Thats why I posted this question? Are you aware of such implementation?

Comment: @Jatin: Where did you hear that?  Can you provide a link?  It's kind of hard to answer that without knowing the context!

Comment: @Jatin: In case you meant *multiple* inheritance (not "multilevel"), then no, that's not available natively in PHP. But you heard right, there are a few workarounds using magic methods to *simulate* MI (related: "mixins"). But they are not very suitable for all purposes and don't come close to proper MI as in other languages.

Comment: Thanks mario for your insight